# Transition from nested job to "main job"

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have 2 job xmls

1.Main_job.xml

```
<batch:job id="main_job">
      <batch:step id="dummyTask1">
        <batch:tasklet ref="dummyTask" />
        <batch:next on="FORWARD" to="dummyTask2"/>
      </batch:step>
      <batch:step id="dummyTask2">
        <batch:job ref="nested_job" />  <!--Forking a nested job -->
        <batch:next on="BACKWARD" to="dummyTask1"/>
        <batch:next on="FORWARD" to="dummyTask3"/>
      </batch:step>
      <batch:step id="dummyTask3">
        <batch:tasklet ref="dummyTask" />
        <batch:next on="BACKWARD" to="dummyTask2"/>
        <batch:next on="FORWARD" to="endTask"/>
      </batch:step>
      <batch:step id="endTask">
        <batch:tasklet ref="endTask" />
      </batch:step>
</batch:job>
```

2.nested_job.xml

```
<batch:job id="nested_job">
      <batch:step id="dummyTask10">
        <batch:tasklet ref="dummyTask" />
        <batch:next on="FORWARD" to="dummyTask11"/>
      </batch:step>
      <batch:step id="dummyTask11">
        <batch:tasklet ref="dummyTask" />
        <batch:next on="BACKWARD" to="dummyTask10"/>
        <batch:next on="FORWARD" to="dummyTask12"/>
      </batch:step>
      <batch:step id="dummyTask12">
        <batch:tasklet ref="dummyTask" />
        <batch:next on="BACKWARD" to="dummyTask11"/>
        <batch:next on="FORWARD" to="endTask"/>
      </batch:step>
      <batch:step id="endTask">
        <batch:tasklet ref="endTask" />
      </batch:step>
</batch:job>
```

You can see that, all the steps have 2 paths.

1. FORWARD
2. BACKWARD

And these paths gets chosen depending on some dynamic boolean condition. Let us say, first, all the Exit codes for the step gets evaluated to `FORWARD`. So these are the sequence of steps, which gets executed

```
1. dummyTask1
2. dummyTask2
 [Nested_job] 3.dummyTask10
 [Nested_job] 4.dummyTask11
 [Nested_job] 5.dummyTask12
```

Let us say when the execution point is on `dummyTask12`, the Exit codes starts to get evaluated to `BACKWARD`. So following are the step executions for the same

```
[Nested_job] 5.dummyTask12
[Nested_job] 4.dummyTask11
[Nested_job] 5.dummyTask10
```

Now for `dummyTask10`, when the exit code comes as `BACKWARD`, SpringBatch throws error saying that flow doesn't exist, which is true (`dummyTask10` doesn't have the flow defined for code `BACKWARDS`). What I want to achieve is, incase of `BACKWARD`, the flow should go back to `main_job` (***or any Main job which has triggered this nested job (dynamically)***)

Is this possible? Is it possible to have a flow definition like this, which will take the execution point to the main job, which forked this nested job?

```
<batch:next on="BACKWARD" to="#{mainJob}"/> <!-- Or something -->
```

[I know this is a little more to ask for, But I am sure SpringBatch experts will find a way to achieve this]

Please let me know if you need more clarity.

**EDIT:**

From a nested job (nested_job), can I write a flow like below within a step, which will make transition to main job?

```
<batch:next on="BACKWARD" to="main_job.dummyTask1"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I'd approach this is as follows:

1. Create a `JobExecutionListener` for the nested_job that sets the job's ExitStatus to be either 'BACKWARD' or 'FORWARD' at the end of the job.
2. Create a `StepExecutionListener` to get the `ExitStatus` from the nested_job and return it as the main_job.dummyTask2's `ExitStatus`.

The above flow would allow the results of the nested job to indicate where the parent job should go.

You can read more about the `StepExecutionListener` in the documentation here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/StepExecutionListener.html
You can read more about the `JobExecutionListener` in the documentation here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/JobExecutionListener.html

Comment: I have a `StepExecutionListener` configured but I am not exactly understanding the solution you are proposing here. Can you please clarify the same ? Also can I evaluate a spring expression within the job transition definition (`<next on="FORWARD" to="#{someExpression}" />`) ?

Comment: I have edited my question, trying to clarify a bit more. Can you please let me know if  it is possible?

Comment: Thank you once again!.. I will give it a try.